# Merging multiple text files together while preserving line order

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have a directory that contains multiple text files. What i need to do is to merge all text files together while preserving the line order for each file and using ; delimeter to seperate the lines from different file and then output the result in a new file.

```
For example

**File 1**

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

**File 2**

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

**File 3**

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

The output i want to get is 
[line1;line1;line1]
[line2;line2;line2]
[line3;line3;line3]
```

I tried using `paste -d'|' *.txt` but that didn't work. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming, but rather about using the command line in Linux. It might get a better reception at [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

`paste -d';' *.txt` worked when saved to a file

Comment: Your post has been flagged as low-quality because of its length. Please add details to your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15062195)

Comment: @JochenJung A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **paste** command :

Paste together corresponding lines of one or more files into vertical columns and we can use the option *-dn* wich will
Separate columns with character *n* in place of *the default Tab*.

finally we redirect the output of the paste command to a file :

```
paste -d';' *.txt > result
```